# Why is the present continuous not possible here? (cost)

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous, present-simple

I have the following exercise in my textbook:

> Flights **always cost / are always costing** a fortune during school holidays.

It is asked to choose the correct or more natural form of **cost**.

The correct answer is **always cost**. Why can’t we use the present continuous to emphasize that the flights cost a fortune so often that it is their characteristic?

There’s another exercise to which this rule applies:

> **You always take / You’re always taking** money from my wallet without asking.

Both forms are correct, according to the textbook. It says that we can use the present continuous here to emphasize the person’s characteristic behavior that the speaker finds annoying.

Why can’t the same rule apply to the previous exercise?

Comment: Because "cost" is a state verb, not an action verb, so you can't use it with *present continuous*.

Comment: In your second example "you're always taking" the present continuous is used to express annoyance at the behavior.